# Octopus Deploy, Deploy microservices

Tags: continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I`m new to Octopus Deploy and I am currently looking for ideas how to manage my deployment process.

My solution consists of 16 microservices. We have Development,Staging and Demo environments. After every commit there is build on Teamcity and if everything is ok we instantly push to Octopus Deploy and create release to dev environment.

Current channels:
I have 16 channels in Octopus for every microservice so I can deploy them separate after successful build in TC.

And I have another 2 channels for Staging and Demo environments.

Current process:
1 step for deploying package for microservice (for all 16 channels I use 1 step and use variables for every channel so it can be more "organized").

[image]

AND

16 "Deploy package" steps for every microservice so I can use them for creating release and deploy ALL microservices to Staging environment simultaneously - like this:

[image]

Problem:
I don`t like that I use these 16 steps for deploying packages so I can use them in creating release to Staging. Can I somehow use "variable list" with microservice variable names or something like that? Maybe I should use different approach and configuration for this case?

Any idea or suggestion will be appreciated. 
Have a nice day.

Comment: Why aren't these 16 different projects in Octopus? I fail to see a reason why you'd deploy 16 different services if only one has changed.

Comment: @gvee I don`t deploy all of them, only one that has changed. I am limited to 1 project atm :(

Comment: Your project should therefore have 16 deployments! Your deployment step needs to be smarter to work out if there's a change to apply or not. Remember that your deployments should work with a "desired state" mentality.

Comment: P.S. there's a variable for this `Octopus.Action.Package.SkipIfAlreadyInstalled`